# Will flutter web apps appear on google

Tags: flutter, web-applications, flutter-web, google-search

I recently developed a flutter web app and hosted it with firebase. But will google be able to show it high up in the search results, because google looks at the text on the website to get the best results. Will google be able to find text on a flutter web app?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46789